# Backbone Calling A function in a View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a function, which I would I like to call and pass a variable from another function. The function being called then returns a variable. I am unsure as to how to complete this task. I have attempted a varying number of ways but none with any success. Here is the sample code:

```
  md5: function  ( str ) {

 return String

}
```

I want to call this md5 function from inside this function:

```
saveTeacher: function(e) {

}
```

How would I achieve this ?

Comment: Are both the functions in same view?

Comment: @CaptainCode  Yes they are

Comment: @CaptainCode, doubt is valid. In case its same view you can straight away use  `this.md5("bla bla string")`

Comment: @Bawn, please mark it as answer if your problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `this`, it should work.

```
saveTeacher: function(e) {
  this.md5(str);
}
```